# UIApplicationLaunch by remoteNotification swift 3 not working

Tags: swift, push-notification, swift3

I have working properly in swift 2.2 but when i convert to swift 3.0 then get error.

```
//If app open by notification
if launchOptions != nil
{
     NSLog("launch------ %@", launchOptions!)

     let  userInfo = launchOptions!(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification) as NSDictionary
     if userInfo != nil
     {
         self.application(UIApplication.shared, didReceiveRemoteNotification: (userInfo)! as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
     }
}
```

Error like

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[NSObject : Any]'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i fixed :-

```
if launchOptions != nil
{
     NSLog("launch------ %@", launchOptions!)
     let  userInfo = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as! NSDictionary
     if userInfo != nil
     {
         self.application(UIApplication.shared, didReceiveRemoteNotification:(userInfo) as! [AnyHashable : Any] as! [String : AnyObject])
     }
}
```

Comment: I do get an error when I use this, what Xcode version are you using? I'm using 8 beta 3 and seems to give an error : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Swift 3. I have to use some cast in order to get the value :

```
    let key : AnyObject = UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification as AnyObject
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions![key as! NSObject] as? [NSObject : AnyObject]{
        self.application(application: application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification)
    }
```